# REST service not returning proper HTTP Code on throwing java.lang.Exception from service method

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

Hi I have a REST web service.

The service method throws java.lang.Exception but the client always receive Http Code 200 which is success.

Shouldn't the rest service return other code than 200?

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes. 200 OK would imply that the request would have succeeded. It sounds like this was not a success so it should have been something else.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is throwing an Exception, **it's supposed to be broken** and **not delivering** whatever your request wanted. That indeed should not return a "**200 OK**" response.

Here's a few things to do:

1. Don't throw java.lang.Exception. Try to be more specific about the exceptions on your code so it's easier to identify the problem when something crashes.
2. Determine WHAT is happening that is throwing that exception.
3. In most cases, send a **400 Bad Request** when something is wrong and the client is guilt for that. If it's a server-side problem, it's usually a **500 Internal Server Error** response. Do a little research on HTTP codes [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).
4. Make sure to document any rules that need to be followed so this problem don't occur in the future.